# Software to combine a MP3 and a CD+G file

Tags: mp3, conversion

I am looking for software to turn MP3 and CD+G into an MP4, MOV, AVI, or any other common video format.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could use CDG Ripper to rip your CD: http://www.tricerasoft.com/karaoke_software/CDG_Ripper_Extraction_Tool.html

Then you could just use Pinnacle Studio, Vegas Pro, Premiere, (probably) Windows Movie Maker or whatever video program you like best to combine them.